# SSH remote login connection refused port forwarding

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, login, remote

A command like:

```
ssh -p 12345 -L 23456:localhost:548 -L 34567:localhost:5900 ServerAcct@soulmate.dyndns.org
```

(not my actual parameters of course)

now returns this:

```
ssh: connect to soulmate.dyndns.org port 12345: Connection refused
```

This worked for years, SSH tunnelling into my host computer from (almost) anywhere in the world. Most recently this was from OS X 10.13.x to 10.11.x. Now the "11" is a "15", i.e. the remote host server has become a 10.15.1, "Catalina".

I learned then documented this here:
http://ctlow.ca/SSH-VPN_MacOSX.html

If I omit the `-p` argument then a tunnel establishes. I am testing this on a local network - but have been told that by using a `dyn-updater` it doesn't matter - and then Screen Sharing works, and File Sharing works but only to external drives, not to "soulmate".

That behaviour also happens if I just use:

```
ssh ServerAcct@soulmate.dyndns.org
```

and use the standard ports, e.g.:

```
afp://192.168.1.{q}:548
```

The `dyn-updater` from dns.com says it's working and can see my IP.

Anyway, using `-p` is for enhanced security. I have the router, a Linksys AC1900 (model number: EA7500), with single port-forwarding set to 12345 (example) as external and 22 as internal (for remote login as usual).

I tested all three of the ports from
https://canyouseeme.org
and all of the redirected (5-digit) numbers work and all of the original, default ports do not.

On the server (remote, host) I have looked at System Preferences:

- Users (nothing to do);
- Sharing;

  - Under "Remote Login" have tried "Only these users" and "All users";
  - Under "File Sharing" have added "soulmate" as a Shared Folder;
- Security and Privacy;

  - The Firewall is off (I would like it on);
  - Privacy, Full Disk Access includes smbd, sshd and Terminal;
- Network (nothing to do).

For thoroughness other little things:

- In 10.15, Terminal now wants to use `zsh` instead of `bash` for Terminal - fine. Failed as above. I have tried reverting it to bash: same. Anyway, it's the local client from which I try to generate the ssh tunnel, and it hasn't changed.
- OS X now wants SMB, it says somewhere, and that AFP is deprecated, but there is the option for either or both (File Sharing panel) and no combination has worked.
- My new Mac Mini has hardware security - does that play into this? The account "soulmate" is both primary and admin.

Should I separate these roles and then just try to log in to "primary" (because the default "Sharing & Permissions" is "system: Read & Write", and "admin/everyone: Read only", and I cannot apparently change that from Finder (so: is that blocking that account, and I probably shouldn't even try to change that from Terminal?)

Is this all one thing suddenly going wrong? It seems like more than one thing.

Comment: That error message indicates that the initial connection to port 12345 is being rejected. This happens before authentication, `-L` port forwards, etc, so all of those are irrelevant. The port forward on the router (12345 external to 22 internal) is the only one that matters. If you're trying to connect from the the same private network the server is on, that adds a level of complication vs. connecting from outside. I'd recommend testing from somewhere else first.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon. Understood. Testing from off-local-network similarly failed. Is this the hardware security chip in a new Mac Mini? I'm going to try making a non-admin userID and see if that helps.

Comment: Sounds more like something in the network setup, but I don't understand your network well enough to say for sure.

Comment: Thanks again Gordon. Two short things for now: this was working fine until I got a new computer with 10.15 on it. The output of the SSH command as above but with "-v -v -v" added is:

Comment: Thx Gordon -was working until new computer w 10.15 -now, SSH output w "-v -v -v" : OpenSSH_7.8p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to soulmate.dyndns.org port 12345.
ssh: connect to host soulmate.dyndns.org port 12345: Connection refused
-ssh_config happened by itself -on router & new computer have opened many things, specified fixed IP many places, added things in Privacy -if omit "-p" parameter then tunnel works locally, not remotely -all ports show open w testing website.